# String boolean value > Boolean, always False!

Tags: java

I'm reading in a csv file and creating a Person object from the fields on each line, one line representing a person. The strings that are being read in are put in an array and then the array elements are assigned as attributes.

By putting print statements in before and after this bit of code I've found that the 'smoker' attribute is set to false regardless of the array element's 'true' or 'false' string value.

```
if(person_array[7] == "true") {this.smoker = true;}
else {this.smoker = false;}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Smoking is no longer allowed in java applications, due to directive EU/01/2009/34267

Comment: I wonder if you knew the directive reference by heart...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do '==' on objects, use `.equals()`.  Also don't do `if (...) boolvar = true; else boolvar = false;`

```
this.smoker = person_array[7].equals("true");
```

or as @Adi and @Peter pointed out

```
this.smoker = Boolean.parseBoolean(person_array[7]);
```

Comment: or `.equalsIgnoreCase` for case-insensitive comparisons, but this only works on `String` objects.

Comment: Possibly compare `"true".equalsCaseIgnore(person_array[7])` is case it could be `null`, of use `Boolean.parseBoolean(person_array[7])`

Answer (score 5):

Paul Tomblin's answer should solve your problem. Consider replacing your code with following line,

```
this.smoker=Boolean.parseBoolean(person_array[7]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Prevent NullPointer Exception

```
if ("true".equals(person_array[7]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` does not do comparison of `String` objects in Java. `==` on objects compare their references.

What you really want is...

```
if (person_array[7].equals("true") ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use person_array[7].equals("true");

== "true" will work sometimes, especially when both of them are literal, ej "true" == "true", but will not always work.

If you want to learn more about it, you can search Java Intern with google. string.intern() is the reason that "string" == string sometimes work.

Comment: Some great answers, thanks. So the == operator works with primitives only?

Comment: @bashcrufter: it works with every value in Java. But it doesn't do what **you** expect it to do with reference types. In other words: it depends on what you mean by "works".

Answer (score 0):

You have to check using .equals("true")

When you compare things using ==, you check that they point (or refer) to the same object. I.e. if you declared String a= "Hello"; String b=a; in that case a would be == to b, since both vars point to the same object.